# report viewer hide column with external parameter

Tags: reportviewer, rdl

Need some help on this, when I list Report According to ListBox, All columns are displayed, but I just want to list according to items in ListBox  so others columns has to be invisible.

I tried some code `= iif(Parameters!TARIH.Value = "True", false,true)` but it doesnt work.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If `TARIH` is a boolean parameter then you can set column `Hidden` property like this:

```
=IIf(Parameters!TARIH.Value, False, True)
```

Or like this:

```
=Not Parameters!TARIH.Value
```

Please note that in rdlc you have to set an *Hidden* property and not a *Visible* property.

Comment: Actually, I'm using reportviewer first time. Types of my columns are "string" and "datetime"

Comment: Is TARIH a parameter or a column in your table?

Comment: column and type of TARIH is datetime

Comment: So you don't want to hide an ENTIRE column but only display or not a value in a cell according to TARIH value. Is this correct?

Comment: I just want to list according to items in ListBox. for example , if I don't select TARIH column, I do not want to appear in the report

Comment: So TARIH is a datetime column and *also* a Parameter: set Parameter as Boolean and use the code in my answer. If it doesn't work please post your error. I also suggest to rename parameter as something like ShowTARIHColumn to differentiate it from TARIH column.